# query regarding Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am  a  fresher as far as Ruby is concerned. i worked in PHP for sometime.  I was wondering if there is some pakage like LAMP or WAMP  as in case of PHP for Ruby too......

If not  at least  suggest me  the best  setup or IDE for Ruby

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something like: [rubystack](http://bitnami.org/stack/rubystack), if this is what you are looking for (rails development).

> BitNami RubyStack greatly simplifies the development and deployment of Ruby on Rails applications. It includes ready-to-run versions of Apache, MySQL, Ruby and Rails and required dependencies. It can be deployed using a native installer, as a virtual machine or in the cloud.

Netbeans, an IDE coming from the java world has ruby support: http://wiki.netbeans.org/Ruby.

Answer (score 1):

**Windows**

If you use Windows, the easiest way to get Ruby working is via the [RubyInstaller](http://rubyinstaller.org/).
If you only want to work on Ruby, Ruby 1.9.1 is your choice. Otherwise, if you want to experiment with Rails, you should try to install Ruby 1.8.7.

There's also a [BitNami Ruby stack](http://bitnami.org/stack/rubystack) but it contains much more stuff than Ruby itself. You don't really need Apache or MySQL to work with Ruby on your local machine because you can use Mongrel and SQLite. In this way, you don't have to bother with additional background processes.

Avoid using Ruby 1.8.6. It's old and it's not convenient to start studying with an outdated Ruby version.

**Mac OS X**

Ruby comes installed by default with Leopard and Show Leopard. If you want a different Ruby version, I suggest to use [RVM](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/).

**Linux**

You can install Ruby by source or with your system package manager.

Answer (score 0):

The [Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/) framework is a great setup for doing web development, and I would highly recommend [RadRails](http://radrails.org/) as your IDE or it's base, [Aptana](http://www.aptana.org/).